# How can I disable the auto Youtube embed in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, video, youtube, embed

When I paste a Youtube URL in the Post Editor in Wordpress, an iFrame is automatically loaded to replace this URL.
How can I disable this behavior and have the URL shown instead - in the Post Editor and on the page itself ?
Can I manipulate this for different types of pages?
E.g. in the Blog posts: embed as iframe as usual.
On a designated "video" page: show URLS instead of iframes.
Cheers and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Insert/edit link (panel option).